# Adding all entries in tuple into one string

Tags: python, tuples

```
('word1', 'word2')
```

If I have a tuple, how can I add all of the words in the tuple into one string?

Desired output:

```
word1 word2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.join`:

```py
tpl = ("word1", "word2")

s = " ".join(tpl)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
word1 word2
```